# source_sink `library(lineutils)' does not exist

Tags: eclipse, prolog, yap

When I try to compile a prolog file, in eclipse with the prodt plugin it gives me this error:

```
source_sink `library(lineutils)'does not exist
```

the project was not created by me, but it is a university project, I don't know where to find this library, which seems to be from YAP. I use SWI Prolog.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick glance to the library source code, it seems that it's compatible with SWI-Prolog. You can copy the `library/lineutils.yap` from the YAP distribution to your SWI-Prolog installation and use it from there. If you copy the file to same place where SWI-Prolog keeps its libraries, you can load it using the same directive:

```
:- use_module(library(lineutils)).
```

Otherwise, you can copy it to your application directory and then load it using simply:

```
:- use_module(lineutils).
```